# How evaluate a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

So basically what i have been struggling with is to evaluate sentence in EF Core.

For example if i have:

```
string condition = "65 < 100 AND 65 > 50"
```

How can evaluate that?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute SQL String in EF Core, So what you need is to write the whole SQL you want in a sctring and then concatenate this part to it. after that you execute it like this

```
myDbContextObject.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlString,params[]);
```

OR

```
myDbContextObject.Table.FromSql(sqlString,params[]);
```